# Pivoting Data based on a field and not hard coding the pivot fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
ItemKey UpdatedOnHandQty    AffectedDate
20406   1594.03     2013-12-27 00:00:00.000
20406   842.132     2014-01-09 00:00:00.000
20406   539.03     2014-02-11 00:00:00.000
20406   486.183    2014-05-12 00:00:00.000
20406   917.86     2014-06-27 00:00:00.000
20406   1314.209   2014-07-29 00:00:00.000
20406   512.261    2014-10-20 00:00:00.000
20406   1394.261    2014-11-12 00:00:00.000
20406   640.19     2014-12-30 00:00:00.000
20406   819.992    2014-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

I want to pivot this data in sql without having to hard code what the pivot field names have to be. I just want there to be a field name for each unique date (Year, Month, Day). Is there a way to pivot based on this field, as i have 100s of unique Affective Dates. This in the end will be filtered down in a BI tool, but for this report i need to pivot the date fields and tableau does not allow for pivots outside of excel.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: Yes, but does it have to be a T-SQL statement? i want a dynamic pivot in a view.

Comment: You cannot create a view with dynamic SQL.  Did you want to `SUM` the `UpdatedOnHandQty` if there's multiple per 1 date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, with SQL Server, you are not able to create a `VIEW` for dynamic `PIVOT's` or for any dynamic SQL at all.

A Stored Procedure can provide you with being able to do this.

**Code: ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/edee7))**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @isNullColumns VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = N''
SET @columns = ''
SET @isNullColumns = ''

; WITH item_dates AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AffectedDate, 112) AS AffectedDate
  FROM table1
)
SELECT @columns += N',' + QUOTENAME(AffectedDate)
  , @isNullColumns += N',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(AffectedDate) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(AffectedDate)
FROM item_dates
ORDER BY AffectedDate

SET @columns = STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '')
SET @isNullColumns = STUFF(@isNullColumns, 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = N'

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ItemKey
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AffectedDate, 112) AS AffectedDate
    , UpdatedOnHandQty
  FROM table1
)
SELECT ItemKey
  , ' + @isNullColumns + '
FROM cte
PIVOT 
(
  SUM(UpdatedOnHandQty) FOR AffectedDate IN (' + @columns + ')
) as p'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Explanation:**

- In order to be able to do this dynamically, you need to store the dynamic SQL statement in a variable (ex: `@sql`).
- The names of the columns are stored in a variable (`@columns`) in order to build the columns dynamically according to the `DISTINCT` values of your `AffectedDate` column.
- The `@isNullColumns` variable is used to get the column names wrapped around an `ISNULL()` function.  Otherwise your pivoted data could end up with `NULL's` all over your output.